# I want to get a list of item from mongodb that is less than or equal filtered by the field created

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is my code:

```
const creationDateOfSentence = new Date( parseInt(bookId.substring(0,8), 16 ) * 1000 );

const allOlderVerses = await Book
                .find({
                    bookId: bookId,
                    created: {$lte: creationDateOfSentence}
                });
```

bookId is a string id of an _id.
I always get an array who is of size 0. Do you know what I am doing wrong? I just want to get items that are older or equal in creation date of this item id: bookId.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between `creationDateOfSentence` and `bookId`? Why a date can be deduced from `bookId`, which is a string id? Better edit your question with sample dataset and expected output for better illustration.

Comment: What datatype is `created` in the schema, and what does it look like in the documents?

Comment: What I understand from this question is BookID is `OBJECT ID (_id)` according to mongodb which is 12 bytes combination `Timestamp+randomValue+incrementor` now you need to extract timestamp from that objectid ? To extract timestamp from that objectId use `ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()` i.e., native method. 
 https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/